# QGIS Visibility Analysis plugin errors with KeyError: 'ID'

Tags: qgis, raster, visibility

**Background:**

I need to conduct a visibility analysis that will calculate depths below the viewer's horizon.

**Process:**

QGIS 3.4 > Processing Toolbox > Visibility Analysis > Depth Below Horizon.

**Input Data:**

DEM:

- 32-bit floating point, single-band tif
- approximately 27,000 X 17,000 cells

Observer Locations:

- Point shapefile with 64 records
- Geometry checks ok

Both the input DEM and shapefile are in the same CRS.

Here's a screenshot of the input:

[image]

**Problem:**

Running the tool results in the following error:

[image]

What does the error mean?

Comment: Please always provide errors as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run the *Create viewpoints* tool first. Then it should be possible to compute depth below horizon. (The tool expects certain columns in the input dataset.)

There is a [tutorial](https://landscapearchaeology.org/2018/visibility-analysis-0-6/) and [test data in the plugin repo](https://github.com/zoran-cuckovic/QGIS-visibility-analysis/archive/test-data.zip).